# How can I measure the overlap between a line and a rectangle?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to measure the overlap between a line segment and a rectangle. For instance, the line segment is represented as 2 points:

`line = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]`

and a rectangle as 4 points:

`rect = [(x3, y3), (x4, y4), (x5, y5), (x6, y6)]`

Is there an efficient way to measure the length of the overlap between the two (if any)?

Here's a simple diagram:

[image]

Edit: Just to clarify, the line segment may partially intersect with the rectangle or even not at all.

Comment: @usr2564301 No, the existence of intersection not guaranteed.

Comment: @KlausD. My current method is to derive the equation for the line segment and the rectangle and solving them. But it's fairly computationally expensive and my hunch is that there should be a better method.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks. I was hoping by 'if any' should suggest an intersection is not guaranteed. I've made it explicit now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the picture

[image: ![enter image description here]

we have

```
P := (x2,y2) - (x1,y1) = (x2-x1, y2-y1)
Q := (x4,y4) - (x3,y3) = (x4-x3, y4-y3)
cos(α) := dotProduct(P,Q)/norm(P)norm(Q)
h := dist((x4,y4),(x5,y5))
```

where

```
dotProduct((px,py),(qx,qy)) := px*qx + py*qy
norm(a,b) := sqrt(squared(a)+squared(b))
dist(A,B) = norm(B-A)
```

Then `d` can be calculated as

```
d := h/sin(α) = h/(sqrt(1-squared(cos(α)))
```

Comment: `sqrt(squared(a),squared(b))` looks a bit strange. `sqrt` is R → R (or C → C) in Python's standard `math` / `cmath` library.

Comment: @9000 Thanks! I've fixed the typo.

Comment: It would also be great to define `dist()` using the Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: @9000 sure. I've added the definition of `dotProduct` too for the sake of completeness.

Comment: There are some intersection cases - you have considered only one.

Answer (score 2):

Find affine transformation to make rectangle axis-aligned. It is just rotation by angle

```
fi = -atan2(y4-y3, x4-x3)
```

Transform coordinates of line segment ends and some rectangle coordinates with this rotation matrix

```
 x' = x * Cos(fi) - y * Sin(fi)
 y' = x * Sin(fi) + y * Cos(fi)
```

Note that now you need only two x- and two y-coordinates for rectangles (`left=x3', right=x4', bottom=y3', top=y6'`)

Apply any l[ine-clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping)

[image]

I'd recommend Liang-Barsky one ([description with code](http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/clipping.html)).
After calculations get distance between clip points or segment ends being inside rectangle
(cases when infinite line intersects rectangle and result parameters `t0` and/or `t1` are out of `0..1` range)

Comment: I don't think line-clipping allows for partial overlaps/intersections.

Comment: @Kar Of course, line-clipping allows for partial overlaps - classic usage is to draw a part of segment inside rectangular window. I expanded answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I am only going over the math part, no coding

find the points of intersection (upperx,uppery) (lowerx,lowery) 
find the distance from the upper point to the the rect right upper corner
find the distance from the lower point to the rect right upper corner
A = subtract the distance of one from the other
B = find the distance from the rect rect right upper corner and right lower corner

you now have A and B for the formula a^2 + b^2 = c^2

enjoy

Comment: I would extend a bit. Look for intersections between the line and _each_ side of the rectangle (intersect the lines, pick the point is it lies inside the segment). You can end up with 0, 1, or 2 _distinct_ points; for 2, the Pythagoras formula gives the distance.

Comment: By using what I have above, I use only a right triangle. And because of the 90 degree angle, I simplify the pythagorean formula to a^2 + b^2 = c^2. Otherwise, there is no need to worry about angles.

Answer (score 0):

I have broken down this answer into three parts:

- calculating the co-ordinate of intersection points
- creating a function to calculate the distance between two points
- putting it all together with the rectangle

I will also use [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/) to visualise examples.

---

#### Intersection

This [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line) gives us a formula for working out the co-ordinate of the intersection point between two lines described by the coordinates:

[image: formula]

*with the co-coordinates: `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)`, `(x3, y3)` and `(x4, y4)`.*

If they do **not** intersect, then the denominator:

```
(x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4)
```

will be `0`.

---

So, using this formula, we can create a function that will return the point of intersection between two lines, *or* `False` meaning that they do not intersect:

```
def intersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4):
    d = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4)
    if not d:
        return False
    return (((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4) - (x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/d,
            ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/d)
```

which we can see works with two tests:

```
>>> intersection(0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 8, 8, 0)
(4.0, 4.0)
>>> intersection(6, 0, 6, 8, 7, 0, 7, 8)
False
```

and you can visualise these with a `matplotlib` plot:

[image: lines]

---

#### Distance

We also need to be able to calculate the *distance* between two points. This can be done using Pythagoras's theorem for the length of the hypotenuse of a triangle:

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

As before, let's put this into a helper function:

```
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2) ** 0.5
```

which we can test:

```
>>> distance(0, 0, 3, 4)
5.0
```

---

#### The main function

We can now create the main function which will implement the two functions defined above.

The steps for this are simply:

- calculate intersections (`False` if there isn't one) between each sides and the line
- remove the cases where there were no intersections
- if there are two intersections points:

  - return the distance between them
- else:

  - return `False` - indicating that the line did *not* intersect the rectangle

Now to implement this in Python:

```
#first 2 points describe the line, last 4 the rectangle
def length_inside(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6):
    intersects = [intersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4),
                  intersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x4, y4, x5, y5),
                  intersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x5, y5, x6, y6),
                  intersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x6, y6, x3, y3)]
    intersects = [i for i in intersects if i]
    if len(intersects) == 2:
        return distance(*intersects[0], *intersects[1])
    return False
```

---

And to test it:

```
>>> length_inside(2, 6, 5, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 5)
2.23606797749979
>>> length_inside(0, 1, 0, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 5)
False
```

which can be seen to be correct through the help of a plot:

[image: plot2]

Answer (score -1):

You didn't exclude external libraries, so here is [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project.html), that is designed for this kind of tasks. Written in C and has a [Numpy array interface](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#numpy-and-python-arrays).

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon

line_list = [(0, 0), (5, 5)] 
rect_list = [(1, 1), (1, 3), (3, 3), (3, 1)]

line_in_rect = Polygon(rect_list).intersection(LineString(line_list))

if line_in_rect:
    print(line_in_rect.length)
else:
    print("no intersection")
```

Doesn't test, though, if it is a rectangle, or if the overlap is only partial.